# Keep \t Characters, While Don't Transform Spaces to Tabs?

Tags: vimrc, indentation

In Vim, how to change the vimrc so that I could keep files' \t characters while I don't want \t characters appear in the newline generated by auto-indentation and tab-button I pressed.

Is this achievable?

Here is what I have appended to the tail of _vimrc:

```
set nu 
set noexpandtab " I want to read \t, not to translate them as spaces.
set tabstop=8 " I want to read \t as 8-space-width.

set softtabstop=4 " This makes the <BS> and <Tab> always 4-space-long.
set autoindent
set colorcolumn=100
set shiftwidth=4
```

Why I have this question: In Python, you can't mix both \t and spaces while indenting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace

```
set noexpandtab
```

to

```
set expandtab
```

.

This will make both auto-indentation and Tabs you manually typed to only spaces.

Now you can type a line containing mixture of both spaces and Tabs with length greater than which tabstop is set,

without worrying some spaces become \t. And actually,

> **`set expandtab`**
> does **NOT** means your files don't contains \t any more,
>
> by typing <Ctrl-Q> + <Tab> you can insert the real \t in your program.

before I solve this problem I think the opposite is true.

Comment: I don't want vim to convert my tabs to spaces. I added to the file /etc/vim/vimrc the line set noexpandtab   but it didnt help. What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

Vim doesn't translate tabs (`\t` characters) to spaces unless you edit the line containing tabs in certain ways or use the `:retab` command. If you don't want tabs in lines you add, even if you type a tab, then you need to set `expandtab`:

```
:set expandtab
```